# CognitoUserManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync limits to 25 results

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, aws-sdk-net

I am using the amazon.aspnetcore.identity.cognito package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amazon.AspNetCore.Identity.Cognito/3.0.0) from https://github.com/aws/aws-aspnet-cognito-identity-provider/.

This within a .net core project.

When calling the GetUsersInRoleAsync, I always seem to only get the first 25 users found for the given role. The role has 26 users, however it always limits to 25. Is there any reason for that, can this limit be ignored somehow?

```
await this.userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(userGroup.ToString());
```

I don't seem to find any related documentation about this.
Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use the UserManager, but you can also list users (and add filters) using the [AWS SDK Cognito service client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoIdentityProvider/MICognitoIdentityProviderPaginatorFactoryListUsersListUsersRequest.html). There is also a paginator that can be used to get all the pages of data.